# How to pass Json object from ajax to spring mvc controller?

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am working on SpringMVC, I am passing data from ajax to controller but i got null value in my controller please check my code below

```
function searchText()
{
   var sendData = {
    "pName" : "bhanu",
     "lName" :"prasad"
   }
  $.ajax({
type: "POST",
 url: "/gDirecotry/ajax/searchUserProfiles.htm,
    async: true,
    data:sendData,
    success :function(result)
    {
    }
 }
```

**MyControllerCode**

```
         RequestMapping(value="/gDirecotry/ajax/searchUserProfiles.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)

       public  @ResponseBody String  getSearchUserProfiles(HttpServletRequest request)
       {
         String pName = request.getParameter("pName");
         //here I got null value
       }
```

any one help me

Comment: what is the `/gDirecotry`? Is it under `WEB-INF` folder?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Hey enjoy the following code.

**Javascript AJAX call**

```js
function searchText() {
   var search = {
      "pName" : "bhanu",
      "lName" :"prasad"
   }

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType : 'json',
       url: "/gDirecotry/ajax/searchUserProfiles.html",
       data: JSON.stringify(search), // Note it is important
       success :function(result) {
       // do what ever you want with data
       }
   });
}
```

**Spring controller code**

```java
RequestMapping(value="/gDirecotry/ajax/searchUserProfiles.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)

public  @ResponseBody String  getSearchUserProfiles(@RequestBody Search search, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String pName = search.getPName();
    String lName = search.getLName();

    // your logic next
}
```

***Following Search class will be as follows***

```java
class Search {
    private String pName;
    private String lName;

    // getter and setters for above variables
}
```

Advantage of this class is that, in future you can add more variables to this class if needed.

**Eg.** if you want to implement sort functionality.

Comment: I have problem: Http status 405, Request method Get not supported

Comment: @H.Aqjn The above example is of POST request, you cannot pass post data in GET request.

Comment: thisss code saved me hehe keep helping +1

Answer (score 8):

Use this method if you dont want to make a class you can directly send JSON  without Stringifying. Use Default Content Type.
Just Use `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestBody`. 
`@RequestParam` Name must be same as in `json`.

**Ajax Call**

```
function searchText() {
    var search = {
    "pName" : "bhanu",
    "lName" :"prasad"
    }
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    /*contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',*/ //use Default contentType
    dataType : 'json',
    url: "/gDirecotry/ajax/searchUserProfiles.htm",
    data: search, // Note it is important without stringifying
    success :function(result) {
    // do what ever you want with data
    }
    });
```

**Spring Controller**

```
RequestMapping(value="/gDirecotry/ajax/searchUserProfiles.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)

   public  @ResponseBody String  getSearchUserProfiles(@RequestParam String pName, @RequestParam String lName) {
       String pNameParameter = pName;
       String lNameParameter = lName;

       // your logic next
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, You need to include the dataType option,

```
dataType: "JSON"
```

And you could get the form data in controller as below,

```
 public  @ResponseBody String  getSearchUserProfiles(@RequestParam("pName") String pName ,HttpServletRequest request)
       {
         //here I got null value
       }
```

Comment: Jquery is going to infer json response data based on the MIME type of the controller response, so it is not required. "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are: ..." http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to pass your whole json in one query string parameter then you can use rest template on the server side to generate Object from json, but still its not the optimal approach

Answer (score -3):

```
u take like this 
var name=$("name").val();
var email=$("email").val();

var obj = 'name='+name+'&email'+email;
  $.ajax({
   url:"simple.form",
   type:"GET",
   data:obj,
   contentType:"application/json",
   success:function(response){
  alert(response);
  },
  error:function(error){
  alert(error);
  }
});
```

spring Controller

---

```
@RequestMapping(value = "simple", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String emailcheck(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("email") String email, HttpSession session) {

    String meaaseg = "success";
    return meaaseg;
}
```

Comment: GET with body really?