# Passing array of objects from JavaScript to spring mvc controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery. I'm dynamically creating objects of rows where the checkbox is clicked in my jsp like this:

```
 var objects={};
 var i=0;
 $(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
       var bar1 = $(this).closest("tr").find(".bar").val();
       var dda1 = $(this).closest("tr").find(".dda").text();
       objects[i] = {data:dda1,bar:bar1};
       i++;
       $('#bar').val(JSON.stringify(objects));
 });
```

and firstly was setting it to a hidden input type like this...

```
  $('#bar').val(JSON.stringify(objects));
```

I was able to read it using the hidden type using the below controller...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/applypage",method= RequestMethod.POST)   

public String ListRequest(@RequestParam("bar") String object )
{
    System.out.println(object);
    return "applypage";
}
```

which gives me the following String...

```
{"0":{"data":"Data3","bar":"N"},"1":{"data":"Data1","bar":"Y"},"2":{"data":"Data4","bar":"N"},"3":{"data":"Data6","bar":"N"}}
```

But after a search on google and referring to many tutorials I found that I have to use ajax and then I tried this code...

```
var data={'objects':JSON.stringify(objects)};
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "applypage", //your valid url
            headers : {
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            data: data,
            success: function(result) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert('failure');
            }
 });
```

But I'm unable to read this value through ajax...

Can anyone please help me in this and I need the code to write the controller also to read the JSON values.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `dataType: "json",` in your ajax code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "applypage", //your valid url
            headers : {
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            data: data,
            dataType: "json"
            success: function(result) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert('failure');
            }
 });
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245544/how-to-pass-json-object-from-ajax-to-spring-mvc-controller

Comment: But i hava an array of objects