# Send Json object by Jquery load

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring

I´m trying to send an json object to my Spring MVC Controller using JQuery load.

If I do with POST as is described here [How to pass Json object from ajax to spring mvc controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245544/how-to-pass-json-object-from-ajax-to-spring-mvc-controller) I can make it works.

But If I try with load, since I cannot specify the content-type, my controller cannot serialize the object since the format is application-www. Any idea how to specify in a load the content type?.

Regards.

Comment: Try converting json object to string and then try to send. At other end do the opposite..

Comment: I try already with JSON.stringify(json), but then the controller tell me "spring mvc Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported"

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` `.load` uses `HTTP` `GET` Method.  This method is not great for passing `json`. It is better to just pass parameters in the query string.  If you do need to pass  `json`, you can use `stringify` method as suggested above and pass `json` in the query string.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand what do you mean with ".load expects html. If you want to get json, you should use .get" I´m sending a json object to my controller, but as parameter. That call will render a modelAndView to be loaded in the proper div

Comment: I try already with JSON.stringify(json), but then the controller tell me "spring mvc Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported"

Comment: From jQuery doc - `The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.`