# Converting ajax GET request parameters to domain object and passed to Spring Controller like @RequestBody

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Here is my jquery ajax ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/some_url",
  type: "GET",
  contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  async: false,
  data: {"attribute_1":"some_value_1","attribute_2":"some_value_2"};,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {}
});
```

Here is my controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some_url", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
public String getDetails(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestBody CustomDTO customDTO) {
}
```

But request does not reach controller method and get 404 error ? If I make it post at ajax and controller level it works. I understand `@RequestBody` works with `POST`
request only.

My question how can i map the input request parameters to domain object in ajax `GET` request  under spring mvc ?

Do I have do define each parameter as `getDetails(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam String pName1, @RequestParam String pName2,...)`  as defined at 
[How to pass Json object from ajax to spring mvc controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245544/how-to-pass-json-object-from-ajax-to-spring-mvc-controller) or is there a cleaner way to wrap them in domain object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Spring @RequestBody support the GET method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956899/does-spring-requestbody-support-the-get-method)

Comment: This is not duplicate. I already mentioned that ` I understand @RequestBody works with POST request only.`. My question is how to convert GET request params to domain object ?

Comment: Then have a look at [Spring MVC: Complex object as GET @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16942352/4105457)

Comment: `async: false` is a bad idea, and is in fact deprecated due to the poor user experience which results from it (mainly, locking the browser's UI during the request so the user cannot click on anything, and if the request goes on too long they may thing the browser itself has crashed). There are almost no use cases where it would actually be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

use `JSON.stringify()` covert data into Json value.

**code**

```
data: ({queryData:JSON.stringify({"attribute_1":"some_value_1","attribute_2":"some_value_2"}}))
```

Then you send data to spring as string parameter  Then convert it by using [jacksonLibrary](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core)

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/some_url", method = { RequestMethod.GET })

  public String getDetails(HttpServletRequest request,
                 @RequestParam String queryData) 
    {

   ObjectMapper myMapper = new ObjectMapper();
QueryData myQueryData = myMapper.readValue(queryData, CustomDTO.class);

  //now you can access data... 
     myQueryData.getattribute_1(); 
    myQueryData.getattribute_2(); 
 }
```